# Issue Embedding Git Bash in RoyalTS

Tags: command-line, bash, git, mintty

I'm trying to embed Git Bash into [Royal TS v5](https://www.royalapplications.com/ts/win/features) and I'm having some issues getting it working.

The way that I have it set up at the moment is as an embedded external application within Royal TS. I have Git Bash running via MinTTY, and I made sure to allow cmd line operation when I installed Git.

The terminal is successfully embedded in Royal TS, but when I try to take a Git action, e.g. `$ git init`, it says:

> bash: git: command not found

To embed the application, I'm using the following Royal TS settings.

Command: C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe

Arguments: --nodaemon -o AppID=GitForWindows.Bash -o AppLaunchCmd="C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -o AppName="Git Bash" -i "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --store-taskbar-properties -- /usr/bin/bash --login -i

Working Directory: C:\Program Files\Git\

The arguments were taken from an existing process, and copied verbatim from the Window Picker functionality of Royal TS.

The part that's troubling to me is that I can take the command and arguments and paste them into the run menu <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and it works perfectly, including the Git commands.

For reference, I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I was overthinking it.

To embed Git Bash into RoyalTS, you can add an external connection with the following properties:

- Command: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
- Working Directory: "C:\your git directory"